# What makes these two sentences cohesive?

Tags: logic

I wrote the text with the help of some native speakers. I'm learning coherence and cohesion. I want to ask how the flow is created between the last two sentences. There isn't any connectors used to link the last two sentences. Is the flow created by repeating the idea of talent loss, the two bold parts?

> Mandating that skilled workers stay in the country that trained them
> helps to avoid brain drain. Without this policy, many of them may **move
> to another country** that pays better and offers a higher standard of
> living. If **a country loses the bright minds** that innovate and build
> companies, its economy will suffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand cohesion very well. According to the influential textbook *Style,* by Joseph M. Williams:

> Sentences are cohesive when the last few words of one set up information that appears in the first few words of the next. That’s what gives us our experience of flow.

While it is true that the phrase **move to another country** is not exactly at the end of the first sentence, it is still a part of the predicate of the independent clause. And the bold part of the second sentence comes at the exact beginning. Overall, your two sentences fit Williams's criteria well enough.